# package-info.java in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

I just downloaded Pet Clinic example (I would like to rewrite it to Spring Portlet MVC) and in every package there is `package-info.java` class. File is empty except the package declaration, so what purpose does this serve?And can I safely omit this in Spring Portlet MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely delete these but normally from my experience you'd just put a description of what the package is for in a comment in this file.

You can find more info on the Oracle website [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#packagecomment)

Comment: Wow, I've never seen such a "best practise". Thanks for clarification

Comment: Yeah I must admit, I only really got into them quite recently when a colleague started writing them but they're pretty useful.  Especially if it's say a package with loads of business logic an you just want a file to describe "what does this package actually do?".  I'm not sure if it generates as a javadoc though like say an interface comment.

Comment: I can see the point but I am not sure if it's really necessary, packages should be rather small with well defined responsibilities and proper names. But that's not always possible so this "helper file" can be sometimes useful, good to know:)

Comment: I do agree it shouldn't be required as code should be self documenting but sometimes the domain of the software can be more complicated than the software itself (especially in some SAP/ERP systems) so I find it useful in those circumstances just to get an overview of the purpose of the package.  Each to their own though, whatever works for your team :)

Comment: @david99world the package-info.java files are generating Javadoc pages for the package, for example: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Furthermore, the first sentence of the package-info is displayed for each package in the overview: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/overview-summary.html)